# Estimate on the integral

Tags: real-analysis, integral-inequality

Suppose $f(x),g(x),h(x)$ are continuous, and $h(x)>g(x)>0$. Does it always hold true that $$\left|\int f(x)g(x)\,\mathrm dx\right|<\left|\int f(x)h(x)\,\mathrm dx\right|?$$

Does it play a role if $f(x)$ changes sign on the domain of integration? If not, what would be the sufficient condition for the estimation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider
$$
\int_{-1}^1 1\cdot x\,\mathrm{d}x=0
$$
and
$$
\int_{-1}^1 \frac{2+x}4\cdot x\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac16
$$

---

Suppose that $f$ doesn't change sign and does not vanish, and that $|X|\gt0$. Then $f(x)=c\,|f(x)|$, where $c=1$ over all of $X$ or $c=-1$ over all of $X$.
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\,\int_Xf(x)h(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\right|-\left|\,\int_Xf(x)g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\right|
&=|c|\left|\,\int_X|f(x)|h(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\right|-|c|\left|\,\int_X|f(x)|g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\right|\\
&=\int_X|f(x)|(h(x)-g(x))\,\mathrm{d}x\\[6pt]
&\gt0
\end{align}
$$

Comment: What if I added the additional requirement that $f(x)$ doesn't change the sign on the domain of integration? would this be sufficient? Because then I have equality of the triangle inequality applied on Riemann sum and I can estimate summand by summand.

Comment: @quallenjäger: I have added a section about that.